# Problem with locomotion of hexabot in ROS2/Gazebo, wondering what the problem might be

Tags: gazebo, ros2, friction, troubleshooting

Hi Robotics Stack Exchange Community,

I am trying to build my first ROS2/Gazebo project and I want to simulate a six-legged robot. I have been trying to troubleshoot and look through documention as to why the robot does not move in the way I expect it to, but I cannot find a solution. I hope that you can help me.

All files can be be found at: https://github.com/madyhr/ARISE_simulation/tree/main/hexabot
(note: I realize this is not the prettiest of projects so bear with me, just trying to make it move for now before cleaning up / optimizing :) )

When I start the simulation with 'gazebo_control_rsp.launch.py' and run the 'initialize_legs.launch.py', it seems to rise up with no problem. [image: gif of hexabot initialization]

However when I run 'tripod_gait.launch.py', it does not move forward at all. See gif below.
[image: gif of hexabot tripod gait]

This is the crux of my question. Why does the robot not move forwards? Why does it shuffle a little from one side to the other? Is this due to some friction problem, is it a problem with the motion itself, or could it be some third thing?

I have tried using different gazebo friction parameters, changing the 'fdir1', 'mu1', 'mu2', 'minDepth', etc. I have also tried to change the friction and damping terms in the joints, but to no avail. The current parameters for the tibia links are:

```
<gazebo reference = "tibia">
        <kp>1e5</kp>
        <kd>100</kd>
        <mu1>1.5</mu1>
        <mu2>1.5</mu2>
        <minDepth>0.002</minDepth>
</gazebo>
```

One problem I suspect is that there's something wrong with the URDF. I used the onshape-to-robot library (https://onshape-to-robot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get the URDF. Before I start redoing the whole URDF, I wanted to ask if it could be something else that's wrong with it.

Thanks in advance!